# Opposite of boondoggle

Tags: business-language

If a trip meant "for business" that results in a trip "for pleasure" can be characterized as a **boondoggle**, then is there a word for the converse, where a trip "for pleasure" (eg. vacation) results in seeking out and taking advantage of a business opportunity?

Comment: **Boondoggle**, according to [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boondoggle), is *"an expensive and wasteful project usually paid for with public money"*

Comment: @NVZ While *boondoggle* can describe a range of wasteful project, it is often applied to trips masquerading as work. And the OP says the term *can be characterized ...*, but does not suggest that the term is limited to that example.

Comment: The use of *boondoggle* in this question is often called a *junket*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's often called a *[busman's holiday](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=busman%27s%20holiday)*

> A vacation during which one engages in activity that is similar to one's usual work.

*American Heritage*

*[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/busmans-holiday)* suggests the term derives from the idea of a bus driver taking a driving holiday

Comment: "Suggests" might actually be Stating The Bleedin' Obvious, I think!

Comment: However, whether one would actually *seek out and take advantage* and have a busman's holiday is more debatable. Isn't it usually undesirable?

Comment: @AndrewLeach And if I spend my vacation clearing the dishes, I am taking a *busboy's holiday*?

Comment: @AndrewLeach When I (a lawyer) kept checking out local courthouses during a trip to the Caribbean, my ex-wife thought it was highly undesirable.

Comment: OED traces the term back to 1893, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus) cites Erik Eckermans's *World History of the Automobile* in dating the advent of buses powered by internal combustion two years after that, so don't rule out horses in imaging "driver" and "driving" in the above answer.

Comment: In some cases one can combine a mostly pleasure trip to a pleasanter clime with a bit of duly paid professional work for a client who happens to be there at the time. Is *that* a busman's holiday?

Answer (score 3):

It's a rather boring and obvious answer, but what I've heard it called is
**[working vacation](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/working-vacation)** (USA)
or
**[working holiday](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/working-holiday)** (UK)

> a trip, sometimes to another country, on which you work

There is also the slang **[workation](http://www.innovateus.net/travel/what-does-workation-mean)**.

> A workation is similar to a vacation where you can take your work
>   along with you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your job and tax bracket, a pleasure trip where you squeeze in some business might be a **tax write-off vacation**.

> [T]he IRS says that you can deduct expenses for taking a business trip.
>   There is no reason the trip shouldn’t coincide with your next
>   vacation. ([Bill Walston, real estate blog](http://revnyou.com/make-your-vacation-a-tax-write-off/))
>
> A fellow . . . needed insurance. Problem was, he was in Branson, Mo.,
>   and wouldn’t be back to Iowa before summer.
>   “No problem,” I told him. “Mary and I have been champing at the bit to
>   go to Branson. We’ll meet you there." . . .
>   Done! A tax-write-off vacation. ([Curt Swarm, *Newton Daily News*, "My
>   tax write-off vacation to Branson"](http://www.newtondailynews.com/2014/03/31/my-tax-write-off-vacation-to-branson/ayvxr70/))

The line here is a bit blurry (though maybe not to the IRS), so this term might also apply to the original situation described (a pleasure trip only *masquerading* as business).